# Xsane only opens when I run it as root

Tags: 14.04, xsane

When I run Xsane as root it works.

When I launch Xsane as a user other than root I get the following error message:

```
failed to open device 'brother4:bus7;dev1':Invalid argument
```

I am using Ubuntu 14.04

The scanner part of my Brother HL-2280DW printer, scanner, copier is working when I run Xsane as root.

Any suggestions would be welcome

Comment: [Edit](https://askubuntu.com/posts/618097/edit) your question and add the Ubuntu version.

Comment: In my 14.04, `xsane` hangs sometime. I have to remove `~/.sane` and it'll start again. Don't know why (this is the reason this is not an answer).

Comment: how do I remove ~/.sane

Comment: I removed ~/.sane and re-started xsane but it didn't help. I get the same error message.

Comment: Maybe there are more sane-related items (folder our file) in your home folder that you should delete (press Control+H and then enter "sane" in the Search box).

Comment: Post the output of `ls -l /dev/bus/usb/007/001`

Comment: crw-rw-r-- 1 root root 189, 768 May  2 03:45 /dev/bus/usb/007/001

Answer (score 0):

This error may happen because your user doesn't have the required privileges to access your scanner. Make sure your user is member of the `scanner` group.

You can add your user to that group from the Unity Control Center, and then logout and login again so the applications can see the change.

Comment: I couldn't figure out how to add user richard to the scanner group from the Unity Control Center  so I used the following command: sudo adduser richard scanner

Comment: and verified by using the command: id richard. When I ran xsane from the terminal as richard I got the same error message as before.

Comment: @RichardLott to let your user get the new privileges you need to log out and then login again. Did you tried to do so?

Comment: `sudo usermod -a -G scanner YOUR_USER` then you either logout and login or run in terminal `sudo su - $USER` (assuming you have sudo privileges), and just run `xsane` after that. should work.